# How to select a JSON field contained in an array

Tags: arrays, json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Hello I have a I have a JSON payload that is is nested, and I am trying to select a field from an array in one select statement, The structure of the fields are like:
but i want to know if i could do it in one select statement

```
|-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- detail: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- object: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- billing_thresholds: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- object: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- plan: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: long (nullable = true)
```

I know i can do something like this which will give me the field i need:

```
display(sT_customer_subscription_events
        .select($"payload.detail.data.object.items.data".getItems(0) as "item_data")
        .select($"item_data.plan.amount"
)
```

But i'm trying to do it within the first select statement, this doesn't work for me below

```
display(sT_customer_subscription_events.select($"payload.detail.data.object.items.data".getItems(0)."plan.month" )
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
originalDF.withColumn("plan",
  from_json($"strJson", schema))
    .select($"plan.payload.detail.data.object.items.data"
      .getItem(0)
        .getField("plan")
          .getField("amount")).show()
```

I obtain the result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|plan.payload.detail.data.object.items.data AS `data`[0].plan.amount|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  0|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Check this out